# Ag-Grid - How to make column width fit content in a custom HeaderComponent and a custom HeaderGroupComponent?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In OnGridReady function, I tried to call `params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()` and `params.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns()` but they're not working. Below are the column definitions with the usage of custom components for both the header group and the header.

```
const frameworkComponents = {
            headerGroupWithCheckbox: HeaderGroupWithCheckbox,
            agColumnHeader: HeaderWithCheckbox
        };

const columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: 'HeaderGroup.1.Name',
                headerGroupComponent: 'headerGroupWithCheckbox',
                children: [
                    {
                        headerName: 'Header1.1.Name'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Header1.2.Name'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Header1.3.Name'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                headerName: 'HeaderGroup.2.Name',
                headerGroupComponent: 'headerGroupWithCheckbox',
                children: [
                    {
                        headerName: 'Header2.1.Name'
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: 'Header2.2.Name'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker or Stackblitz example please.